# Como ativar o minimap para Jupyter notebook (vscode)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ipython-notebook

Estou tentando ativar o minimap para Jupyter notebook no vscode, porem não estou conseguindo, seria possivel?

Erro aparente no minimap "Drag a view here to display"

Comment: O que quer dizer "notebook"? Verifique se a configuração está true: `"editor.minimap.enabled": true` ou pressione C+, e no campo de busca que aparecer digite minimap, a seguir procure a opção `minimap shown`, veja se está habilitada.

Comment: O problema já foi reportado no repositório oficial (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/14210), eh um problema do programa, [não fazendo parte do escopo do Stack Overflow em Português](/help/on-topic).